# formencode invalid return type

Tags: python, error-handling, webforms, formencode

if an exception occurs in form encode then what will be the return type??

suppose

```
if(request.POST):
        formvalidate = ValidationRule()
        try:
            new = formvalidate.to_python(request.POST)
            data = Users1( n_date = new['n_date'], heading = new['heading'], 
                           desc = new['desc'], link = new['link'], 
                           module_name = new['module_name'] )
            session.add(data)
            session.commit()
        except formencode.Invalid, e:
            errors = e
```

how we can find the field wise error

Comment: it is not a python language question but related to some web framework, so will you please tell which one it is?

Comment: sorry i work with django python framework

Comment: it doesn't look like django, i think you are using formencode form validation lib in some webframework e.g. pylons/turbogears?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using formencode(http://formencode.org)

you can use unpack_errors to get per field error e.g.

```
import formencode
from formencode import validators

class UserForm(formencode.Schema):
    first_name = validators.String(not_empty=True)
    last_name = validators.String(not_empty=True)

form = UserForm()
try:
    form.to_python({})
except formencode.Invalid,e:
    print e.unpack_errors()
```

it will print a dict of errors per field.

you can use formencode.htmlfill.render to render all errors, in different ways, read
http://formencode.org/htmlfill.html#errors

Comment: what do you mean by this also show error, it shows a dictionary from that you can get any field error e.g. print e.unpack_errors()['first_name']

Comment: ok so may be you can select it as answer, if it does what you need

Comment: you can vote up a answer if you click up arrow, near top-right of the question, and you can select the answer by click check/tick mark.